# Creating a 2D array for snakes and ladders game

Tags: java, arrays, swing, grid, 2d

I am creating a small snakes and laddders game. I have multiple classes, but the two I am concerned with are my BoardGame class and my Grid class.

After doing some research, I decided the best way to track the movements of my players would be by making them move through a grid, I also believe that this class should be seperate from what i have read.

Currently, on my BoardGame class - which contains the GUI - I have created a JLabel with an image of a 100 square snakes and ladders game. What i want to do next is then overlay a grid, itself consisting of 100 squares, in which the players will move. Their movements and positions on the board are to then be tracked in a seperate Tracker class.

From what I have read, using a 2D array such as `int[][] multi = new int[10][10];` seems to be the way to approach this. Is this correct? And if so, how would I then mark the snake heads and bottom of the ladders, and also, how would I then transfer this grid to my BoardGame class (the GUI)?

Thanks in advance, here is the BoardGame class. I have not included my grid class as i am unsure as to which direction to proceed with it.

```
public class GameBoard extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private JLabel Board;

/**
* Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GameBoard inst = new GameBoard();
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public GameBoard() {
    super();
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        {
            Board = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(Board);
            Board.setText("jLabel1");
            Board.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/board.jpg")));
            Board.setBounds(199, 0, 742, 484);
        }
        pack();
        this.setSize(963, 523);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //add your error handling code here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using a 2 dimensional array is probably the best way to do this.
You can create the array like this as you mentioned.

```
int[][] multi = new int[10][10];
```

but, if you want to draw the board out yourself, its probably better to define it like this

```
int[][] multi = {
     {0,0,0,0,0},
     {0,1,1,0,0}
};
```

in this array, you could make 1 stand for a ladder and 0 stand for a blank space.
to add more rows, all you need to do this

```
int[][] multi = {
     {0,0,0,0,0},
     {0,1,1,0,0},
     {0,1,0,0,0}
};
```

Comment: Sounds simple enough. And perhaps a -1 for snakes?

Comment: Yup, you can use any integer you want :)

Comment: Super. thanks for your help. Just another question, how would I then transfer this over to my Board Game class, and have it appear directly over my image so the squares link up?

Comment: You could use a for loop that iterates over the entire array, and if it is a certain number, it renders that piece at that position.

Comment: Better to place the data into a text file and then read it in and not hard-code it in an inflexible way in the program.

Comment: @10Replies sorry Im not too sure I understand, would what you said essentially allow my grid to be referenced from the Board game class. I think I need to create an instance of it, but I am not 100% sure

Comment: Ok, to allow your grid to be accessed from the board game class, just add a new method called getGrid and have it return the board then you can do    int[][] grid=otherclassname.getGrid()